# Only processing complete group messages Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

Is there a way to make it so that camel will only process grouped messages in a queue that has a complete sequence? For example, if I send message (GroupSeqNumber) 1 and the last message (GroupSeqNumber) 3 I don't want it to process the message until message (GroupSeqNumber) 2 enters the queue. Right now my implementation will only process messages after the last message is sent regardless if the grouped messages have a complete sequence or not.

```
from("temp:queue:temp").aggregate({Combines body of grouped messages}).process({Processing class});
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at the options `completionPredicate` and `strategyRef`? They might help you to achieve that.

Comment: I tried to use a completionpredicate after aggregate where in aggregate I add a header to indicate that the message is complete but it just gets stuck at the completionpredicate and I think it sends message 2 to a different consumer if we were following the example in the post.